# Creating a plain non-component class using a razor file

Tags: razor, blazor

Is it possible to create a plain non-component class using a razor file?  The idea is to take advantage of the simplified syntax for generating `RenderFragment`s, from a class that is not intended to be a component or a page.  e.g.

```
@inherits object
@code {
    // some other stuff

    public RenderFragment Foo => @<span class="foo"></span>;

    public RenderFragment Render(string? name) => __builder =>
    {
        // some other stuff
        <text>@name</text>
    };
}
```

where the resulting class should be equivalent to:

```cs
public class Whatever /*: object*/
{
    public RenderFragment Foo => __builder =>
    {
        __builder.OpenElement(0, "span");
        // etc
    };

    public RenderFragment Render(string? name) => __builder =>
    {
        __builder.AddContent(0, name);  // or whatever
    };
}
```

---

Trying exactly the above results in the generated code reporting an error:

```
Whatever.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder): no suitable method to override
```

which is not entirely surprising, since the generated code includes an override for that method, which of course does not exist in a plain class.

I was hoping that by not including anything outside of `@code` the compiler would not attempt to override that method, but sadly that does not appear to be the case.  Is there some other trick that can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes form `@inherits object`.
That does indeed make a "non-component class", but why?

Just leave that out and make your helpers `static`:

#### Whatever.razor

```
@inherits ComponentBase
@code {
    // some other stuff

    internal static RenderFragment Foo => @<span class="foo"></span>;

    internal static RenderFragment Render(string? name) => __builder =>
    {
        // some other stuff
        <text>@name</text>
    };
}
```

And then you can use it like any static function:

```
@Whatever.Render("J Doe")
```

Comment: Why? Because, as stated, I don't want to make a component.  I don't want it to be valid for someone to try to use it as a component somewhere else.  I just want a plain class.

Answer (score 2):

### Revised Answer

Yes you can.  You can create a minimum requirement class that the Razor compiler will accept.

1. It doesn't need to implement `IComponent` as there is no intention of using it as a component.
2. It needs a virtual `BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)` method for the Razor compiler to override: it's where it compiles all the markup in the main block.

```
public abstract class MinRazor
{
    protected virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) {}
}
```

You're Razor file then inherits from it.

`RenderStuff.razor`

```
@inherits MinRazor
@code {
    public string Message { get; set; } = "No one set me!";

    public RenderFragment GiveMeADiv => __builder =>
     {
         <div class="p-2 m-2 bg-light">
             <div class="p-2 m-2 bg-primary text-white">
                 @Message
             </div>
         </div>
     };
}
```

The only baggage that the compiled code has is a blank `BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)`.

Here's the output file the compiler produces:

```
public partial class RenderStuff : MinRazor
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
    {
    }

    public string Message { get; set; } = "No one set me!";

    public RenderFragment GiveMeADiv => __builder =>
    {
        __builder.OpenElement(0, "div");
        __builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "p-2 m-2 bg-light");
        __builder.OpenElement(2, "div");
        __builder.AddAttribute(3, "class", "p-2 m-2 bg-primary text-white");
        __builder.AddContent(4, Message);
        __builder.CloseElement();
        __builder.CloseElement();
    };

}
```

Comment: The question states:  _"The idea is to take advantage of the simplified syntax ..."_

Comment: @HenkHolterman - semantics I know, but I read the primary question as "Is it possible to create a plain non-component class using a razor file?" :-)  I've made a minor change to the answer.

Comment: I'm already aware of that.  This was not the question.

Comment: No problem.  I've totally revised my answer based on your answer.

Comment: That is clever and interesting to know. I still think the actual 'savings' are irrelevant though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Agreed, but it's not our code.  One advantage is you can't try to use it as a component.  (I misread the question initially - and once you get it in your head,.... )

Comment: It's certainly an interesting approach; I did consider something similar but I wasn't super happy with it since you need the extra dangling base class. And it still limits which classes you can use as a base, although now that I think of it, it should be possible to use a CRTP generic base to get around that (not that this is any prettier).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is (currently at least) not possible; the closest working approach seems to be to implement it as a component anyway, but indicate that it is not intended to be used as such:

```
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    // some other stuff

    public RenderFragment Foo => @<span class="foo"></span>;

    public RenderFragment Render(string? name) => __builder =>
    {
        // some other stuff
        <text>@name</text>
    };
}
```

This unfortunately stills means that it will carry around some extra state baggage from inheriting `ComponentBase`, and it can't inherit any other (non-component) base class.

---

Making the render methods `static` and simply calling them from the "real" class as [Henk Holterman suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72783817/43534) is probably the best compromise, although it would still need something like the `OnInitialized` override to discourage misuse.

Ideally you'd mark the static methods component as `@internal` too, to further reduce the scope of possible mis-use, but sadly [that's not implemented yet](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5516).

Comment: You _can_ use `internal static` here, and that would indeed make much sense in a library. Together with a `throw` in the initialization path you would have covered most abuse cases. The overhead from ComponentBase is irrelevant, you (should) never `new()` this component.

Comment: True, marking the static methods as `internal` is a good idea, even if the component itself can't (yet) be internal.  The part talking about `ComponentBase` overhead was referring to the approach exactly as first described above, where you do instantiate the component -- but you're right that this is probably not the best way to do it, as explained further down and in your answer.

Comment: See my revised answer on how to build a minimum class that the Razor compiler will accept, and what the compiled file looks like.